# Draggable tab control for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, custom-controls, tabcontrol

Are there any tab controls available for Delphi where the tabs can be clicked and dragged to reorder them, like in a web browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Available *in* Delphi:

http://delphi.about.com/b/2009/05/13/how-to-move-pagecontrols-tabs-using-dragndrop.htm

Comment: It is always (read: often) best to use the native Win32 controls when possible.

Answer (score 2):

Raize PageControl (RC5 current version) has this ability.

[Raize Software](http://www.raize.com).

I've always liked his stuff.

Answer (score 2):

ExpressPageControl by devexpress can also do this.
An article on how to do this from their knowledgebase: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/kb/p/A1056.aspx